# CSS How to insert a page-break within a block element

Tags: css, printing, page-break

I want to separate data to different pages when printing. Each (printed) page is within #pagewrapper.

My CSS:

```
#pagewrapper+#pagewrapper {
page-break-before: always; 
}
@media print {
    #navigation, #cleardiv, #footer, .noprint {
        display: none;
    }
    #printed-article {
        border: 1px solid #777;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #pagewrapper {
        margin: none;
    }   
}
```

When my content is added to a page with a preset header/nav/footer, the page breaks no longer exist...

I don't know how to describe the situation more. I think it has something to do with the content being in a block. Is it possible to be in a block but still have page-breaks?

Comment: You have multiple #pagewrapers? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: You say "when my content is added..." but can you acknowledge that your ___CSS___ is also getting added?

Comment: Yes, using Chrome's "inspect element" I can confirm that the   page-break-before: always;  is not being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem (and solution). The site already had .css files for their header/nav/footer etc. This was the code that broke the page-breaks:

```
#content {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background: none;
    font-size: 10pt
}
```

I couldn't change it, because it's used elsewhere, but I added the following override to my own .css:

```
#content{
    position:inherit;
    right:auto;
    float:inherit;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto; padding: auto;
    background: none;
}
```